# How to get current value of ndarray in function?

Tags: python, numpy

There is the function which operates with numpy.ndarray:

```
def func(x):
    print x # here I need a current value of ndarray
    return 5*x
```

For some calculation I need a current value of passed ndarray, something like `np.nditer()` while iterating.

Output:

```
x = array([1, 2, 3]
In [52]: func(x)
[1 2 3]
Out[52]: array([5, 10, 15])
```

Some ***upd***:

I need to plot next sequence:

[image]

I've wrote function which perfectly works with single values:

```
In [54]: def my_formula(x):
    ...:     return sum([1/(math.sqrt(i)) for i in range(1, x+1)]
```

but I need to transfom it for plotting:

```
def graph(formula, x_range):  
    x = np.array(x_range)  
    y = formula(x) # numpy ndarray!
    plt.plot(x, y)  
    plt.show()
```

so here

```
return sum([1/(math.sqrt(i)) for i in range(1, x+1)]
```

I need a current element of `ndarray`, not a full range for `range(1, x+1)`

Comment: where do you want to store the current value of the passed array

Comment: What do you mean by "current value"? Is `[1,2,3]` not exactly the current value in your example?

Comment: @AndrasDeak 1 after that  2, and 3 respectively for each calculation.

Comment: @NaderHisham I need it just to perform calculation on for each element from x `ndarray`.

Comment: I don't understand your question either. You should write an example of exactly what is it you trying to achieve.

Comment: @yzT updated question.

Comment: Do you need each element of the sum, or the *partial* sum up to a given index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple transformation of your function would be:

```
def graph(formula, x_range):  
    x = np.array(x_range)  
    y = [formula(xx) for xx in x]
    y = np.array(y)     
    plt.plot(x, y)  
    plt.show()
```

Without plotting I can illustrate this with:

```
In [541]: x=np.arange(5)
In [542]: np.array([my_formula(i) for i in x])
Out[542]: array([ 0.        ,  1.        ,  1.70710678,  2.28445705,  2.78445705])
```

We can be more elaborate, and talk about speeding this up, using more numpy functions, etc., but this is the simplest change that will get you going.

Comment: In retrospect, this indeed makes sense:) I just couldn't figure out OP's `formula` and `my_formula` and whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly and you want to plot the partial sum of your series, then you can use

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

parsum=lambda nvect: [np.sum(1.0/np.sqrt(np.arange(1,nmax+1))) for nmax in nvect]
x=np.arange(1,101)
y=parsum(x)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

This will define a `lambda` named `parsum`, which accepts the `n` values for which it will compute the partial sum up to the given `n`.

If you want to plot consecutive values anyway, you can just call

```
parsumvec=lambda nmax: [np.sum(1.0/np.sqrt(np.arange(1,n+1))) for n in np.arange(1,nmax+1)]
y=parsumvec(101)
x=np.arange(1,len(y)+1)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

which `lambda` will generate all the partial sums up to its scalar input argument `nmax`.

Output with `nmax=101`:

[image: output]